# Hacer subconsultas (IN) en rawquery ó query de Android SQLite

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Estoy desarrollando un programa en Android Studio, y necesito hacer una consulta, el cual se compone de dos consultas anidadas con "in" pero no tengo idea como, ya que las que encuentro utilizan consultas simples.

¿Alguna idea?

```
SELECT  nota.*, par_procesoelemento.nombre_pre, par_tipogarantia.nombre_dpr
    FROM ope_nota nota
    INNER JOIN ope_elemento
    on ope_elemento.id_ele = nota.id_ele
    inner JOIN par_procesoelemento
    on par_procesoelemento.id_pre = nota.id_pre
    LEFT JOIN par_tipogarantia
    on par_tipogarantia.id_dpr = nota.id_dpr
    where ope_elemento.id_ele = 1
          and nota.version_nta in (
                        select max(n.version_nta)
                from ope_nota n
                where n.id_pre = nota.id_pre
                and n.id_ele =nota.id_ele)
```

Esta es mi consulta en mysql, Yo guardo los registros por versiones y deseo consultar de las ultimas versiones cuales tienen estado ACEPTADO o cuales tiene estado PENDIENTE, esta consulta me trae todo los registros con sus estados. Ahora en sqlite en android studio no se como hacerlo. 
La consulta mas avanzada que he hecho es con INNER JOIN, pero no con consultas anidadas con IN.

```
 public Cursor obtenerNotas(String elem, String suc, String pro) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = baseDatos.getReadableDatabase();

    String selection = String.format("%s=? and %s=? and %s=?",
            BaseDatos.Tablas.OPE_NOTA + "." +ColmNota.ID_ELE,
            BaseDatos.Tablas.OPE_ELEMENTO+ "." +ColmElemento.ID_SUC,
            BaseDatos.Tablas.OPE_ELEMENTO+ "." +ColmElemento.ID_PRO);
    String[] selectionArgs = {elem,suc,pro};

    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    builder.setTables(NOTA_JOIN_ELEMENTO);
    String[] nota = new String[]{
            BaseDatos.Tablas.OPE_NOTA + "." +ColmNota.ID_PRE,
            BaseDatos.Tablas.OPE_NOTA + "." +ColmNota.VERSION_NTA,
            BaseDatos.Tablas.OPE_NOTA + "." +ColmNota.ESTADO_NTA
    };
    return builder.query(db, nota, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Si pudieses colocar parte del código para poder entender mejor la situación. O bien de un esquema de consulta que debiera hacer. Ya que podremos enfrentarnos mejor al problema

Comment: Disculpa la demora, soy nueva en esto. pero ya agregue codigo y consulta sql.

Comment: No hay problemas, siéntete bienvenida :D

Comment: Si todavía tienes este problema podrías ayudarnos a ayudarte colocando en alguna página que permita probar sqlite (como por ejemplo https://www.db-fiddle.com/) las instrucciones SQL para crear las tablas que usas, algunas instrucciones INSERT para poner algunos datos de ejemplo, la sentencia SELECT con tu intento más cercano. Luego pones el link en la pregunta y también incluyes una tabla con los datos esperados de la consulta. Este es un ejemplo de pregunta que lo tiene https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66430/como-puedo-hacer-un-sql-que-contenga-un-array-de-objetos-y-que-esos-objetos-con

Answer (score 0):

No se mucho de sql, pero si te puedo ayudar con el cursor

1) probar la consulta en algun programa externo (uso SQLIte browser para ver el contenido de la base de datos, que tambien tiene una pestaña pra hacer consultas)

2) luego crear un cursor y haces la consulta (lee la documentacion...hay varias formas de hacer consultas en sqlite asi entiendas los parametros de cada metodo)

```
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(queryString,null);
```

dode db es el archivo de base de datos (un archivo sqlite en la memoria del dispositivo) que se supone ya esta abierto como corresponde

3) Poner el indice del cursor al principio para poderlo iterar

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

4)Con un bloque do-while iterar el cursor para obtener los datos

```
      do {
        log.d(TAG,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ColumnName")));
      }while (c.moveToNext());
```

donde ColumnName es el nombrede la columna de donde desesas obtener el dato

Esta clase tiene muchos metodos que te van aservir y facilitar las cosas, te sugiero leas  la documentacion [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary)