# ¿Como puedo hacer un sql que contenga un array de objetos y que esos objetos contengan 2 datos de columnas?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Llevo [este `sql`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fCUAMmkELGm63F2DQw35Gj/3)

El resultado de las 2 columnas `modelos_id` y `modelos_nombre` las quisiera unir dentro de objetos, lo intento hacer como dice [la documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE).

[Acá lo que intento hacer](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fCUAMmkELGm63F2DQw35Gj/6), la consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT mar.nombre AS marcas, json_object(array_agg(mod.id), array_agg(mod.nombre)) as modelos
FROM marcas AS mar
INNER JOIN modelos AS mod ON (mar.id=mod.marcas_id)
GROUP BY mar.nombre
ORDER BY mar.nombre
```

Pero este me retorna:

> ERROR:  no existe la función json_object(integer[], character varying[])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Devolviendo un object `jsonb`

Si lo que quieres es respetar el `GROUP BY` con mar.nombre y en un solo campo tener un objeto con el id como clave y el nombre como valor se puede usar la función `jsonb_object_agg`:

```
SELECT mar.nombre AS marcas, 
    jsonb_object_agg(mod.id,mod.nombre) as modelos_nombre
FROM marcas AS mar
INNER JOIN modelos AS mod ON (mar.id=mod.marcas_id)
GROUP BY mar.nombre
ORDER BY mar.nombre
```

Esto obtiene como resultado

```
LG       {"1":"LG-001","2":"LG-002","3":"LG-003"}
Samsung  {"4":"Sam-004","5":"Sam-005","6":"Sam-006"}
Sonyview {"7":"Sony-007","8":"Sony-008","9":"Sony-009"}
```

## Devolviendo un array `json`

Si lo que quieres es respetar el `GROUP BY` con mar.nombre y en un solo campo tener la **lista** (o **array**) de id y nombre de marca se puede usar la función `json_agg` para la función de agregado y `json_build_object` para crear el elemento individual:

```
SELECT mar.nombre AS marcas, 
    json_agg(json_build_object('id',mod.id,'mod',mod.nombre)) as modelos_nombre
FROM marcas AS mar
INNER JOIN modelos AS mod ON (mar.id=mod.marcas_id)
GROUP BY mar.nombre
ORDER BY mar.nombre
```

dinstintas posibilidades en `json_build_object` te van dando distintos resultados. Puedes probar la que desees. Con esta el resultado es:

```
LG       [{"id":1,"mod":"LG-001"},{"id":2,"mod":"LG-002"},{"id":3,"mod":"LG-003"}]
Samsung  [{"id":4,"mod":"Sam-004"},{"id":5,"mod":"Sam-005"},{"id":6,"mod":"Sam-006"}]
Sonyview [{"id":7,"mod":"Sony-007"},{"id":8,"mod":"Sony-008"},{"id":9,"mod":"Sony-009"}]
```

puedes probar con `json_build_object(mod.id::text,mod.nombre)` para que el id sea la `key` del par y la marca el valor.

### json vs jsonb

A los efectos de este problema da lo mismo, se puede usar array u object en ambas variantes. Recomiendo jsonb, pero ese es otro tema.

## Devolviendo un `ARRAY` puro de registros

Lo siguiente devuelve un **array de array**, otra vez acá se puede poner dentro del array_agg lo que desees para que el elemento interno sea del tipo que necesites.

```
SELECT mar.nombre AS marcas, 
    array_agg(array[mod.id::text,mod.nombre]) as modelos_nombre
FROM marcas AS mar
INNER JOIN modelos AS mod ON (mar.id=mod.marcas_id)
GROUP BY mar.nombre
ORDER BY mar.nombre
```

### ¿Qué se puede meter dentro de array_agg?

Alternativas para meter dentro de array_agg. El problema de meter un array dentro es que hay que pasar todo al mismo tipo, si se quieren respetar los tipos una buena alternativa es usar row:

- `row(mod.id,mod.nombre)` que devuelve una registro (tupla) respetando los tipos

Cualquier cosa que devuelva un único valor se puede meter dentro de `array_agg`, por ejemplo cualquier función que devuelva un json (lo cual no tendría mucho sentido, porque sería mezclar json dentro de array comunes).

Comment: Gracias, muy buena respuesta. Una pregunta mas, ¿Se puede ordenar el `json` por `mod.nombre` de manera `asc`?.

Comment: Sí, en todas las funciones de agregación se les puede pedir un orden dentro de la llamada a la función: `json_agg(json_build_object('id',mod.id,'mod',mod.nombre) order by mod.nombre)`. De todos modos por definición de json los objetos no están ordenados: *An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.* [http://www.json.org/]

Comment: gracias hermano.

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez esto?

```
SELECT mar.nombre AS marcas, 
       row_to_json(row(mod.id, mod.nombre)) as modelos
FROM marcas AS mar
INNER JOIN modelos AS mod ON (mar.id=mod.marcas_id)
GROUP BY mod.id,mar.nombre
ORDER BY mar.nombre
```

Comment: El inconveniente de esta solución es que cambia el `GROUP BY`. La pregunta de Pablo no queda del todo clara, pero me imagino que quiere un registro por cada `mar.nombre`.