# json vs jsonb postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

¿Cual es la diferencia entre `json` y `jsonb`?

El usuario [@EmilioPlatzer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/184/emilio-platzer) me dio una respuesta a [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66430/como-puedo-hacer-un-sql-que-contenga-un-array-de-objetos-y-que-esos-objetos-con/66453#66453)  donde usa estos 2, pero no veo la diferencia.

De hecho, el usuario comenta lo siguiente:

> **json vs jsonb**
>
> A los efectos de este problema da lo mismo, se puede usar array u object en ambas variantes. Recomiendo jsonb, pero ese es otro tema.

Acá un fiddler donde uso [`json`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fCUAMmkELGm63F2DQw35Gj/9) y acá un fiddler donde uso [`jsonb`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fCUAMmkELGm63F2DQw35Gj/10)

Personalmente no veo ninguna diferencia, ni en tiempo de respuesta del sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jsonb` almacena nos datos en un formato binario, además permite índices. Mientras que el formato `json` guarda el texto, incluyendo los espacios. Debido a la conversión el formato `jsonb` puede ser un poco más lento **al guardarlo**, pero gracias a su índice es mucho más rápido en las búsquedas.

La propia [documentación de Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) indica que a menos que haya una razón específica para usar el otro tipo, **se debe preferir `jsonb`**.

Answer (score 5):

## Resumen

La diferencia es interna. ¿qué se almacena y cuándo se hace la conversión?

- **json**: almacena el texto, la conversión se hace en cada `SELECT`, ventajas: el insert es más rápido, se almacena textualmente lo que se especifica (y no hay una única manera de escribir un objeto JSON).
- **jsonb**: almacena el objeto, la conversión se hace en cada `INSERT`, ventajas: los selects son más rápidos, lo que se almacena está estandarizado

Deberías preferir **jsonb** en todos los casos, salvo que el `INSERT` sea tu operación crítica.