# Migración con un valor OpenStruct en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo el modelo Casa

Con los atributos:

```
2.6.6 :106 > Casa.first
  Casa Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "casas".* FROM "casas" ORDER BY "casas"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Casa id: 1, nombre: "Mis hijos", direccion: "calle 4 con esquina sur", created_at: "2021-01-30 13:59:35", updated_at: "2021-01-30 13:59:35"> 
2.6.6 :107 > Casa.first.class
  Casa Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "casas".* FROM "casas" ORDER BY "casas"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => Casa(id: integer, nombre: string, direccion: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) 
2.6.6 :108 >
```

Tengo la variable color de tipo OpenStruct.

```
2.6.6 :112 > color = OpenStruct.new
 => #<OpenStruct> 
2.6.6 :113 > color.sala = 'blanca'
 => "blanca" 
2.6.6 :114 > color.cocina = 'azul claro'
 => "azul claro" 
2.6.6 :115 > color
 => #<OpenStruct sala="blanca", cocina="azul claro"> 
2.6.6 :116 >
```

Quiero agregar este tipo de variable a mi modelo, intenté crear un atributo del tipo store

```
class AddColorToCasa < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :casas, :color, :hstore
  end

  enable_extension "hstore"

end
```

El nuevo atributo del modelo Casa se ve así:

```
2.6.6 :123 > Casa.first.class
  Casa Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "casas".* FROM "casas" ORDER BY "casas"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => Casa(id: integer, nombre: string, direccion: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, color: hstore)
```

Para al intentar salvar la variable color en el atributo casa.color. me da el siguiente error:

```
2.6.6 :119 > casa = Casa.first
  Casa Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "casas".* FROM "casas" ORDER BY "casas"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Casa id: 1, nombre: "Mis hijos", direccion: "calle 4 con esquina sur", created_at: "2021-01-30 13:59:35", updated_at: "2021-01-30 13:59:35", color: nil> 
2.6.6 :120 > casa.color = color
 => #<OpenStruct sala="blanca", cocina="azul claro"> 
2.6.6 :121 > casa.save
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):121
TypeError (can't cast OpenStruct)
```

No se como hacer para poder guardar una variable de tipo OpenStruct en una tabla en Ruby on Rails

**NOTA:** Estoy trabajando con una base de datos postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes almacenar un `OpenStruct` en la base de datos como un `JSON` (utilizando el tipo de datos `jsonb`<sup>1</sup>. Para hacerlo solo debes convertirlo a `Hash` y `ActiveRecord` se encargará de serializarlo (i.e. convertirlo a `JSON`):

```
color = OpenStruct.new(sala: 'blanca', cocina: 'azul claro')

casa = Casa.new(color: color.to_h)
casa.color
#=> {"sala"=>"blanca", "cocina"=>"azul claro"}
```

La ventaja de este tipo de datos es que `ActiveRecord` lo trata como un `Hash` todo el tiempo así que, para efectos prácticos, el atributo `color` de `Casa`, es un `Hash`; por ejemplo, si quisieras obtener el color de la sala:

```
casa.color["sala"]
#=> "blanca"
```

Considerando lo anterior, a menos que tengas una razón específica para utilizar `OpenStruct`, yo te recomendaría utilizar un `Hash`, así te evitas estar convirtiendo los valores de `OpenStruct` a `Hash` y de `Hash` a `OpenStruct`.

Si decides utilizar `OpenStruct`, podrías evitarte la conversión manual sobrescribiendo los métodos *setter* y *getter* del atributo `color` en el modelo `Casa`:

```
class Casa < ApplicationRecord
  def color=(ostruct)
    self[:color] = ostruct.to_h
  end

  def color
    OpenStruct.new(self[:color])
  end
end
```

Su uso sería transparante:

```
color = OpenStruct.new(sala: 'blanca', cocina: 'azul claro')
casa = Casa.new(color: color)
#=> #<Test id: nil, color: {"sala"=>"blanca", "cocina"=>"azul claro"}>

casa.color
#=> #<OpenStruct sala="blanca", cocina="azul claro">

casa.color.sala
#=> "blanca"
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>También existe el tipo `json`, pero se recomienda más `jsonb`; puedes ver más al respecto en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66471/json-vs-jsonb-postgresql/66474).</sup>